# sending an image through a socket in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, webserver

```
std::ifstream file(localPath.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);

file.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);

while(file.tellg() != -1)
{
    char *p = new char[1024];

    bzero(p, 1024);
    file.read(p, 1024);

    printf("%ld\n", file.gcount());

    n = send(fd, p, strlen(p), 0);
    if (n < 0) {
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    } else {
        printf("---------%d\n", n);
    }

    delete p;
}

file.close();
```

Actually the image which I m trying to send is png (size: 27892bytes) As far as reading is concerned every byte is being read properly. But, while writing them into socket only few bytes are being written. Need help on this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strlen()` expects a `NULL` terminated string, not binary image data, when you use `strlen()` it stops at the first `NULL` (or zero) byte and the image data could contain zero at the first or second byte or anywhere, so you can't use `strlen()` to find the size of the image buffer. you should use the buffer size instead:

```
n = send(fd, p, 1024, 0);
```